# Change "to:" address in Outlook after clicking send

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

Here's the situation:

I receive emails from a colleague that, as a consultant, has multiple email accounts.   He's not always careful which one he uses.  However, replies back to him *have* to go to a specific email account regardless how it was sent.  There are almost always others that need to be copied on the "reply all".   Since it's impractical to reliably review every email reply, and there are several of us in the this situation, I'm looking to hack my way around this.

It looks like I can create a rule in Outlook that, maybe, adds his preferred email as a CC address but then it means the email reply goes to 2 places.  My preference is that it only goes to one place.

Bonus question:  Is there any way to make this work when replying from my iPhone?  That is, is there a server-wide approach?

Double-bonus:  My coding days are a distant memory, but I was able to hack together a VBA script for something else a couple of years ago.  Anything to point me in the right direction would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: You could set up an in-between email account with specific rules for handling emails from his account(s) and from yours.  When that account receives an email from any of his email accounts, it could forward it to your email.  And when you reply, and that account receives an email from you, it could forward it to only the one account of his that you want to receive these emails.  Kinda hacky but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the reply-to address in his outlook profile. It should follow him around to other clients.